# Forest tree with labelled edges and no nodes on the ends

Tags: trees, forest

... one upon the time ... :)  I draw this tree

[image]

by CorelDraw! for presenting convolution coding rules, which I like now to redraw and modernize with help of forest package. I stuck at followings:

- skip drawing nodes on the end of tree
- placings edge labels on better/shorter way
- make tree layout symmetrical at all tree levels

[image]

I kindly ask help me in the following to resolve above listed problems as well to add names to nodes in tree for later use, for example draw input line with condition for branching, for append some legend and auxiliary images or for `callout` nodes (balloons) for some explanations.

So far I manage to write the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               margin=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{forest}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{document}
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
      circle, font=\small\sffamily,
             fill = blue!60!black,
     minimum size = 4mm, 
        inner sep = 0.5pt,
             text = white,
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             edge = {draw, semithick},
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) |-
      (.child anchor) -- % intermediate point
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
             grow = east,
            s sep = 2mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 12mm,   % level distance
               }
[a
    [b,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}
        [d,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}
            [d,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}]
            ]
            [c,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}]
            ]
        ]
        [c,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}
            [b,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}]
            ]
            [a,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [a,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}
        [b,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}
            [d,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}]
            ]
            [c,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}]
            ]
        ]
        [a,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}
            [b,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{01}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{10}}]
            ]
            [a,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{11}}]
                [,edge label={node[xshift=-9mm,fill=white]{00}}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a pattern to the labels?

Comment: Your partial labelling doesn't match the target image, which doesn't help.

Comment: @cfr, yes, labels has pattern (maybe not so obvious). I edit my question and add all labels to edges and also try to make my question more clear. I check labels an as far as I can see, they are now equal to labels on target image.

Comment: Well, what ***is*** the pattern? Is there a rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say about the labelling without knowing what it should look like. You can define a variable to hold it and use that, define a style or use one of various automated-labelling options, if there's a pattern.

The rest is fairly straightforward, I think.

- Distinguish terminal nodes from the others by testing to see if they have any children.
- Use `name` to name a node for later reference.
- Use invisible terminal nodes for spacing and symmetry.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\forestset{
  declare toks={way label}{},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={% style of tree nodes
    semithick,
    font=\small\sffamily,
    edge = {draw, semithick},
    grow = 0,
    s sep = 2mm,    % minimum sibling distance
    l sep = 12mm,   % minimum level distance
    edge path'={
      (!u) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label}
    },
    circle,
    minimum size=4mm,
    inner sep=.5pt,
    anchor=center,
  },
  where n children=0{}{
    draw,
    fill = blue!60!black,
    text = white,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where way label={}{}{
      edge label={
        node [pos=.75, fill=white, font=\sffamily] {\forestoption{way label}}
      },
    },
  }
  [a
    [b, way label=11
      [d
        [d
          []
          []
        ]
        [c
          []
          []
        ]
      ]
      [c
        [b
          []
          []
        ]
        [a
          []
          []
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [a
      [b
        [d, name=zarko
          []
          []
        ]
        [c
          []
          []
        ]
      ]
      [a
        [b
          []
          []
        ]
        [a, name=bob
          [, way label=11
          ]
          [, for current and ancestors={way label=00}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \draw [<->, shorten >=20pt, shorten <=20pt] (zarko) -- (current bounding box.east |- zarko) -- ++(5pt,0) |- (bob);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted tree]

Comment: almost done! Now I need first to understand all your changes/improvements to my MWE, This will take me a while :)

Comment: I have problem to understand syntax of `where n children=0{}{...}`, all others make me less troubles :). Only thing which is left over is how to consider common `\tikzset{...}` (defined in document preamble) in images , which I like to add to `forest`. Thank you for nice answer.

Comment: @Zarko It just tests if the node has any children. If not, do nothing. Otherwise, draw, colour and fill. It is just excluding the terminal nodes and do something to all the rest.